# Openstack Horzion Install -> TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html

Tags: django, django-templates, openstack-horizon

I'm currently installing Openstack Stein, and now I'm trying to install Horizon, following the tutorial.
I end up in this error:

```
ERROR django.request Internal Server Error: /horizon/auth/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
  response = response.render()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 106, in render
   self.content = self.rendered_content
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
   template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
   return select_template(template, using=self.using)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 47, in select_template
   raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html
```

I didn't create any template, it is a fresh installation from the Openstack Tutorial.

I googled it but didn't found any answer.

Thks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
Downgrading Django version from 2.2 to 1.11.
Reinstalled it and it worked.